# how to terminate pipe operation in @ngrx/effects?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

In below code, I'm getting the length of the collection as observable from Firestore.

```
getUserCartLength(uid:string){
    return this.db.collection('users/'+uid+'/cart').valueChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(docs=>{return docs.length})
        )
}
```

And this method is accessed by the @ngrx/effects as follows

```
@Effect()
userExist$ = this.actions$.ofType(UserAuthTypes.YES_USER_EXIST).pipe(
    map((action:YesUserExist)=>action.user),
    switchMap((user)=>{
        return this.userService.getUserCartLength(user.uid)
                .pipe(
                    map(length=>{
                        console.log(length);
                        return new InitializeUserCart(length);
                    })
                )
    }),
)
```

And in the component, I'm using store method to dispatch actions after checking user exists or not

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.logService.isUserExist().subscribe(user=>{
      if(user) this.store.dispatch(new fromUser.YesUserExist(user));
      else this.store.dispatch(new fromUser.NoUser());
  })
}
```

everything works fine as long as user logged-In. When user logged-out it throws an error as below

```
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

My understanding about this error is that pipe operation is still trying to access database

Is there any way to close pipe operation in ngrx/effects or any other approach please help me !

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

When do you do `switchMap` from `stream1` to another `stream2` - double check that you really want to listen to every `stream2` action except first one.

It seems that the solution is to add `first()` to the inner stream in the effect.

Comment: using first() gives me error: @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.0.4): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds. i think first() emit's one value and then closes connection, in this case i need back-end connection all the time